# Is Twilio Taskrouter capable of truly dynamic routing?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am confused with the **taskrouter** functionality , is it strictly `skill based` ? or can we have *truly dynamic routing* on arbitrary business logic ? suppose we have 10 workers with exactly same set of skills. Is it possible to route the task to a particular worker of our choice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can dynamically route any logic you want , it accepts standard json and can use that to select an agent